# how to instantiate a class with parameters outside constructor?

Tags: java

I create a class like this

```
public class Something{

private int foo;
private int bar;

    public Something(int f){
        setFoo(f)
    }

    public int getFoo(){
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(int f){
        this.foo = f;
    }

    public int getBar(){
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(int b){
        this.bar = b;
    }

}
```

How can I create a new instance of this class with something like this

> Something smt = new Something(15) **.setBar(10)**;

When I try to do it it marks an error saying that its a **void** when smt requires a **Something object**.

I dont really know how this is called in english but I hope my question is clear

Comment: the constructor is void so I believe the error is kind of obvious. You will have to split into two calls or add a new constructor parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are talking about the fluent builder "pattern".

Simply have your `void` setters return `Something` and add `return this;` as your last statement in the method body.

E.g.:

```
public Something setBar(int b){
    this.bar = b;
    return this;
}
```

You can then chain method invocations while "building" your `Something`, e.g.:

`Something mySomething = new Something(42).setBar(42).set...`

Comment: Thanks It worked, and also thanks for the name of the pattern I will look further into it.

Comment: @LuisVega you're welcome. Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) will help.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `setBar(..)` is not returning anything.

You should do something like

```
Something smt = new Something(15);
smt.setBar(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the class this way and it will work:

```
public class Something{

    private int foo;
    private int bar;

    public Something(int f){
        setFoo(f)
    }

    public int getFoo(){
        return foo;
    }

    public Something setFoo(int f){
        this.foo = f;
        return this;
    }

    public int getBar(){
        return bar;
    }

    public Something setBar(int b){
        this.bar = b;
        return this;
    }

}
```

This way anytime you use a setter you return the instance. You can even chain the setters.